# Cisco VPN Client + RSA Secure ID Token on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cisco-vpn-client, rsa

I guess I got a laptop which is beyond IT's support. It has 8G ram, so I chose to use Windows 7 64-bit OS. Everything is fine except the VPN connection.

Since IT is not going to support this non-SOE image, I find another way to get the .sdtid token file which, I believe, is used by RSA Secure ID Client.

Can someone tell me what software I need to install and how to set it up? I heard Cisco VPN Client does not support Windows 7 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cisco's AnyConnect VPN client](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps2308/index.html) supports WIndows 7 64-bit. Personally, I use [ShrewSoft's VPN Client](http://www.shrew.net/software) to connect to a Cisco VPN, but I'm not sure if it supports Secure ID.